# What are the different list of registered names a host can have in a URL?

Tags: url

I'm trying to get a clearer definition of the registered names that are allowed in a URL.

In [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/URL) is says that:

> A "host", consisting of either a registered name (including **but not
>   limited to** a hostname), or an IP address...

So it includes hostnames which are also domain-names, but what are the rest of the registered names allowed in a URL that it refers to?

Can someone give me a list of the remaining possibilities or examples that do not use hostnames/domain-names?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the URI standard, the [`host` subcomponent](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3986#section-3.2.2) can consist of an `IP-literal`, an `IPv4address`, or a `reg-name`.

The current standard doesn’t define the term *hostname* (previous versions might have). Per [section D.2](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3986#appendix-D.2), specifications that have a grammar rule called `hostname` should use the grammar rule `reg-name` instead.

The quoted passage from the Wikipedia article likely refers to the common meaning of [hostname](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hostname) (bold emphasis mine):

> […] a label that is assigned to a device **connected to a computer network** […]

The section [*Internet hostnames*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hostname#Internet_hostnames) has an example:

> So, for example, both *en.wikipedia.org* and *wikipedia.org* are hostnames because they both have IP addresses assigned to them. The domain name *pmtpa.wikimedia.org* is not a hostname since it does not have an IP address (as of now), but *rr.pmtpa.wikimedia.org* is a hostname. A hostname may be a domain name, if it is properly organized into the domain name system. A domain name may be a hostname if it has been assigned to an Internet host and associated with the host's IP address.

<sub>(Note that the given examples might be out of date.)</sub>

tl;dr: If a `reg-name` can be used to access a computer in a network, this `reg-name` is also a hostname.

Comment: Thanks for this. Makes sense to not be a hostname if there is no host haha.