# URL parts canonical terminology

Tags: url, terminology

I've been reading around and it seems there is no very well coherent and fully accepted terminology for the URL parts. Is that true? I'd like to know which standards exists for URL parts terminology. What is the most common? Is there any well established standard?

I found the following:

1. [RFC3986 section 3](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3986#section-3)

---

```
     foo://example.com:8042/over/there?name=ferret#nose
     \_/   \______________/\_________/ \_________/ \__/
      |           |            |            |        |
   scheme     authority       path        query   fragment
      |   _____________________|__
     / \ /                        \
     urn:example:animal:ferret:nose
```

2. [`window.location`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Location#Properties) from Javascript on browsers

---

```
protocol://username:password@hostname:port/pathname?search#hash
-----------------------------href------------------------------
                             -----host----
-----------      origin      -------------
```

- `protocol` - protocol scheme of the URL, including the final ':'
- `hostname` - domain name
- `port` - port number
- `pathname` - /pathname
- `search` - ?parameters
- `hash` - #fragment_identifier
- `username` - username specified before the domain name
- `password` - password specified before the domain name
- `href` - the entire URL
- `origin` - protocol://hostname:port
- `host` - hostname:port

3. NodeJS, module [`url`](https://nodejs.org/api/url.html#url_constructor_new_url_input_base)

---

Above the line with the URL you see node's `url` module old API, whilst under the line you see the new API. It seems node shifted from a RFC standard terminology to a more browser friendly standard terminology, that is, similar to browser's `windows.location`.

```
┌────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┐
│                                              href                                              │
├──────────┬──┬─────────────────────┬────────────────────────┬───────────────────────────┬───────┤
│ protocol │  │        auth         │          host          │           path            │ hash  │
│          │  │                     ├─────────────────┬──────┼──────────┬────────────────┤       │
│          │  │                     │    hostname     │ port │ pathname │     search     │       │
│          │  │                     │                 │      │          ├─┬──────────────┤       │
│          │  │                     │                 │      │          │ │    query     │       │
"  https:   //    user   :   pass   @ sub.example.com : 8080   /p/a/t/h  ?  query=string   #hash "
│          │  │          │          │    hostname     │ port │          │                │       │
│          │  │          │          ├─────────────────┴──────┤          │                │       │
│ protocol │  │ username │ password │          host          │          │                │       │
├──────────┴──┼──────────┴──────────┼────────────────────────┤          │                │       │
│   origin    │                     │         origin         │ pathname │     search     │ hash  │
├─────────────┴─────────────────────┴────────────────────────┴──────────┴────────────────┴───────┤
│                                              href                                              │
└────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┘
```

4. Highly ranked [article](https://www.mattcutts.com/blog/seo-glossary-url-definitions/) from Matt Cutts

---

`URL: http://video.google.co.uk:80/videoplay?docid=-7246927612831078230&hl=en#00h02m30s`

- The protocol is http. Other protocols include https, ftp, etc.
- The host or hostname is video.google.co.uk.
- The subdomain is video.
- The domain name is google.co.uk.
- The top-level domain or TLD is uk. The uk domain is also referred to as a country-code top-level domain or ccTLD. For google.com, the TLD would be com.
- The second-level domain (SLD) is co.uk.
- The port is 80, which is the default port for web servers. Other ports are possible; a web server can listen on port 8000, for example. When the port is 80, most people leave out the port.
- The path is /videoplay. Path typically refers to a file or location on the web server, e.g. /directory/file.html
- This URL has parameters. The name of one parameter is docid and the value of that parameter is 7246927612831078230. URLs can have lots parameters. Parameters start with a question mark (?) and are separated with an ampersand (&).

---

Some of my concerns:

1. Is `window.location` a standard or based on a standard?
2. Shall I call `http://` the `protocol` or the `scheme`?
3. Shall I say `host` or `authority`?
4. Why nor `window.location` nor node have properties for TLD or other domain parts, when available?
5. The terminological difference between `hostname` (example.com) and
   `host` (example.com:8080) is well established?
6. for node `origin` does not include `username:password@` whilst for `windows.location` it does

I'd like to follow on my code a well established standard or best practises.

Comment: Regarding host/hostname, related question: [What are the different list of registered names a host can have in a URL?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/48394378/1591669)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The URI standard is [STD 66](https://tools.ietf.org/html/std66). This is currently mapped to [RFC 3986](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3986).

So for the generic URI syntax, these terms are authoritative, currently:

- `scheme`
- `authority`
- `userinfo`
- `host`
- `port`
- `path`
- `query`
- `fragment`

Comment: Can you kindly be more precise with a single example wherein every portion applies? Thanks

Comment: @JoãoPimentelFerreira: The example in your question does this already, as it’s quoted from the standard. It only misses the `userinfo` subcomponent: `foo://userinfo@example.com:8042/over/there?name=ferret#nose`

Comment: The problem is that some concepts are missing. Ex.: `origin` of `windows.location` is missing.

Comment: @JoãoPimentelFerreira: "Missing" in which sense? The URI standard simply doesn’t define a term for the combination of `scheme`, `host` and `port`, because it doesn’t need such a term. -- [RFC 6454](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc6454) defines the concept of origins.

Comment: I opened a bounty. Kindly do check it the description. Thanks a lot anyway

Answer (score 1):

Terminology depends on which  architectural style/technology you are using.

I prefer REST style for identifying different parts of my url [REST URI Standard](https://restfulapi.net/resource-naming/)

But I repeat again there are no single universal standard to represent URL

Comment: which standard would you recommend for a project with `nodejs`, `expressjs` and `javascript`?

Comment: For Node/ express REST is defacto standard though it's not the only one. Node has very good support for REST

Answer (score 1):

Java [java.net.URL](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/net/URL.html) follows [RFC 2396](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2396.txt) which is an older version of RFC 3986.

Python's [urlparse](https://docs.python.org/3/library/urllib.parse.html) also follows RFC 3986, except for using `netloc` instead of `authority` possibly for legacy reasons.

In other words, I'd follow RFC 3986.